# How to calculate DPS of your pet?

Tags: torchlight-2

Using [arcane statistic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86332/torchlight-2-how-powerful-is-a-weapon-exactly) panel I am able to understand with good precision how much DPS I do with my weapon, but how can I calculate the DPS of my pet? I didn't find anything in arcane panel and the damage shown on pet inventory seems not accurate, I am quite sure that attack speed does not influence that value.

Is there something I can use to understand the real DPS of my pet?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the `combatlog` but I'm not at home to check if pet dps is also parsed in there, should be worth a try anyway

Comment: Failing all else, there's always the fallback with a notepad and a stopwatch. :)