# What is the math behind the weapon strength?

Tags: torchlight-2

I'm looking for example showing the math behind the calculation of the weapon strength. I'm aware of other [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86332/torchlight-2-how-powerful-is-a-weapon-exactly), but can someone show the actual math in the following weapons?

Pistol 1:

- Weapon screen: Physical damage 26 - 52, +5 Physical damage, Speed .64, DPS 67
- Character screen (under strength): 37-67
- Arcane screen: 37-67, DPS 82

Pistol 2:

- Weapon screen: Physical damage 26 - 52, +7 Electrical damage, Speed .64, DPS 68
- Character screen (under strength): 39-69
- Arcane screen: 31-61, DPS 85, +8 Electrical damage

Hammer (two-handed):

- Weapon screen: Physical damage 81 - 163, +7 Poison damage, Speed 1.32, DPS 97
- Character screen (under strength): 103 - 198
- Arcane screen: 95-190, DPS 118, Speed 1.28, +8 Poison damage

Well, how does the game get these numbers and should I sling the pistols or wield the hammer?

Comment: http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=47838

Comment: Thanks. But it's just the math behind the skill points.

Comment: Yes, usually this is the math that makes the basic calculations differ from the simple math you can do for Weapon DPS. For Eg: your hammer, the Weapon DPS is calculated with the formula (Mean(minDmg,maxDmg) + Dmg Modifiers)/Weapon Speed. which is 123+7/1.32 = 97(rounded down). The arcane stats puts all other stat mods and any other dmg modifiers from equipment and displays the number. The above link must clear it up for you. If you need more info let me know, cause this should be enough for you to figure out how to get to those numbers, from the basic weapon DPS.

Comment: Well, that's the point. Why does the damage on the character screen and on the arcane screen different? Especially when the damage on the arcane screen is smaller, since all my modifiers are positive. Is 118 DPS in my example the final DPS? I would like an example of the calculation from you. And one more thing, why don't you put your answer as an answer? I think it's a better place for this discussion.

Comment: I can help you out. A better look at your stats and equips can be helpful in giving you accurate calculations. Please post them here and I will formulate the DPS for you.